# how do i user css for usercontrol label?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to change color of label which is in usercontrol.
as it in in usercontrol i'm failed to do this using css.

I did like following :
inside myusercontrol.ascx

```
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="user control"></asp:Label>
```

StyleSheet1.css

```
#Label2
{
    color:red;
    }
```

webform.aspx

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="home" ></asp:Label>

      <uc:myuc  runat="server" ID="uc1"  />
</div>
```

As in normal aspx page it is working fine but not on usercontrol please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never style against asp.net id:s since they might change in the markup. If you view source the label (rendered as a span) propably won´t have id="Label2" when it´s inside the usercontrol. Rather style it using a class or set clientidmode static if that suits your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
uc1.Style["Color"] = "Red";
```